# iOS Bluetooth list of devices already connected?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

Is there any way to generate a list of devices that are already connected to the iOS device, i.e. find devices that were connected via Settings > Bluetooth? Devices that I'm interested in are likely already connected. Is there any way to interact with those system connected devices via our own apps? I've tried using scanForPeripheralsWithServices with CBCentralManager but seems to only work with devices that are advertising. As mentioned, devices that I'm interested in are likely already connected.

Comment: What sort of devices are you looking for?  Headsets/speakers can be found via the AVFoundation.

Comment: No device in particular, just trying to determine what is already connected to the system (LE devices).

Comment: If it is an LE device, then simply scan for the service(s) you are interested in.  LE devices only show in Settings->Bluetooth while another app has a connection or pending connection or if the peripheral was bonded in order to support encrypted characteristics.  If another app already has a connection to the peripheral then you probably won't be able to make a connection as peripherals typically only support a single central connection at a time.  You can also use `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices`